C# in Visual Studio: Can not edit or change the position of item in the tab page
I meet some problem when I try to put and edit items into a tab page while editing with environment below:
language: C#
editor  : Visual studio 17.9.7
MS.net framework : V4.8.09032

When I try to drag a item into the tab page from the toolbox, it blocks the action and shows error message "system.nullreferenceexception 'object reference not set to an instance of an object.'", but I can add item by clicking the item in the toolbox and locate the item in the tab page.

I can't move the item I put in the Tab page, when I try to drag it to a the position and released, it will return to its original position in the tab page, But I can resize the item.


is there any setting I need to modified ?
move the item in the tab page while editing

The first thing I would suggest is to updated VS. Version 17.10.2 has just been released. That may address the issue.

If the issue persists, what framework are you targeting? Try a new project with the same framework for the same behaviour. If you're targeting .NET Core (.NET 5 and later are based on .NET Core) then try a project targeting .NET Framework 4.8.1 and vice versa. If the issue persists, you might try repairing VS, which is a specific option in the installer.

@jmcilhinney Thanks for the reply, I updated to V17.10.2 but it still persists, I'll try other actions, Thanks!


It is a known issue with multi monitor setup when secondary monitor(s)
have different DPI setting than primary monitor. Unfortunately we
don’t have a solution for it yet but we will continue to investigate
it.

See the error report:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Adding-any-component-to-Winform-in-VS201/824685
And there are bug reports saying the error occurs in VS 17.9.1.
Try updating Visual Studio to the latest version 17.10.2.

Hi Minxin,  the issue was solved once I removed the external monitor, but it persists when I updated to V17. 10. 02, I guess I have to handle the resolution of monitors,  Thanks for your kindly feedback!

Glad to know this answer worked for you.
